# How to create a symbolic link in an other directory?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

There are two directories `A` and `B` and a file `F` which is located in `B`. The working directory is `B`.

How can you create a symbolic link in `A` pointing to `F` in `B` without changing the directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ln -s $(pwd)/F /full/path/to/A/link
```

Just supply the absolute path to both the file you want to link to and the the new symlink file. You can use `pwd` as a shortcut for your current path (e.g. `B`).

Comment: Great, thx for the quick help.

Answer (score 2):

Try This (in bash);

```
 ln -s $(pwd)/${F} ${A}
```

Or this syntax in other shells

```
 ln -s `pwd`/${F} ${A}
```